# Does KStream filter consume every message?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I have used Kafka in the past, but never the streams API.  I am tasked with building a scalable service that accepts websocket connections and routes outbound messages from a central topic to the correct session based on user id.

This looks ridiculously simple using KStream<String, Object>.  From [one online tutorial](https://kafka-tutorials.confluent.io/filter-a-stream-of-events/kstreams.html):

```
builder.stream(inputTopic, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), publicationSerde))
        .filter((name, publication) -> "George R. R. Martin".equals(publication.getName()))
        .to(outputTopic, Produced.with(Serdes.String(), publicationSerde));
```

But does the filter command consume every message from the topic and perform a filter in application space?  Or does **KStream<K, V> filter(Predicate<? super K,? super V> predicate)** contain hooks into the inner workings of Kafka that allow it only to receive messages matching the correct key?

The wording on the KStream<K,V> javadoc seem to suggest the former: "consumed message by message."

If the only purpose of the filter is to consume every message of a topic and throw away those that are not relevant, I could do that by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct - messages need to be deserialized, then inspected against a predicate (in application space)

> throw away those that are not relevant, I could do that by hand

Sure, you could, but Kafka Streams has useful methods for [defining session windows](https://kafka.apache.org/28/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#session-windows). Plus, you wouldn't need to define a consumer and producer instance to forward to new topics.

Comment: One other consideration:  if my only goal is to identify messages that match a specific websocket connection using user id as a key, I can add the user id to the headers of the message and skip deserialization.  KStream will require a deserialization of the data, which is not altogether a trivial addition to the CPU / memory consumption / garbage collection.

Comment: Unless you're handling deserialization manually, the record would still contain deserialized data by the time the client gets a handle on the object with headers